# Signal Root to Execute a Program

Tags: linux, redhat, automation

I have a program that must be run as root, and needs to be triggered by an outside process to start (it is triggered by a build process completion).  It is not on a schedule, so cron is not an option.  We originally had direct ssh, but that must now be disabled, so that is not an option.  Is there a way to remotely notify root to run a specific program on that machine?  Not any program, but a specific, authorized program?

I can log in, sudo to root, and run it manually without a problem.  We're trying to automate part of an installation process after a build.  This is under Redhat 6.4.

Comment: When you remotely notify the server, there must be a client-server connection between two server. Do you have another alternative than SSH?

Comment: you could run cronjob to check a specific file from an remote server with wget or curl,  run a script if it is available. Or setup a mailadress on the host which triggers a script via procmail or /etc/aliases on receive. It might be difficult to make it secure though

Comment: The solution can be to include an update to a job queue after the completion of your outside process and polling mechanism (for instance managed by cron) on your server that monitors that job queue and starts your job once it detects its trigger. Call your polling mechanism an "agent" and add reporting, progress monitoring, error handling etc. and you get the enterprise solution and google buzz words: [Job scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) and "Workload Automation".

Comment: When you say "installation process", are you installing software or installing the OS?

Comment: Installing customized IBM software.  The OS is already installed (RHEL 6.4).  We have a base package and this process installs customizations on it.  Their software requires and is installed as root.

Comment: @HBruijn, I had thought about this approach, I just didn't want to reinvent something if there was already a way to do it.  In my case I was going to call it a `daemon` ;)

Comment: I haven't seen an already-packaged way to do this. In addition to what others have suggested, another option is to write your own process (daemon) that listens on a tcp port and if it receives an appropriate packet, then it will execute the command(s) you need.

Answer (score 2):

When you make it SSH, make it SSH as another user with a key and allow that automation user to execute that very specific command as root, with sudo. So you would execute the command from the build server something like `ssh sudo /scripts/myscript`.

Comment: If you do this, also make very sure that the new user doesn't have write permission to /scripts/myscript or /scripts/. If they have write permission, they can modify the script to run arbitrary code, which defeats the point of locking things down this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [func](http://fedorahosted.org/func) for remote execution, but you could also use a queueing system such as [beanstalk](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) or the PubSub functionality in [redis](http://redis.io) and a local daemon on the destination side that polls the queue and executes commands based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that monitors a named pipe (or a webpage, or a network socket) and executes your code in response.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a way to perform a task, for which ssh more or less is the tool everybody would use, and then say it must not be done using ssh. That means you are likely to end up with a worse solution.

If you do have ssh access, but just can't run a root shell over ssh, it can still be done. In fact, the proper solution may very well not be to have access to a root shell.

There could be access to ssh as root, but not using password, but rather only by using a key in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Such a key can be restricted to only running a specific command, for example you could have a line like this:

```
command="ls /tmp",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ...
```

If this is not acceptable either, you could ssh in as a different user and run an suid root executable. However writing a suid executable requires lots of care, so I wouldn't recommend it. It could be located in a directory, which is only accessible to a specific group, in order to limit who can run it.

You can also have a daemon listing on a port, and then run the command once that port is accessed. That potentially opens you up to many kinds of attacks. The safest daemon is one, that never reads anything from the network socket, and that may be suitable in some cases. But that also makes it very hard to do any sort of authentication.

Bottom line, you're likely better off using standard tools, and ssh might just be the standard tool you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on something quite similar, but a little more polished, whereby access is granted through Samba and I notify is used to trigger execution.

I'm documenting it on my blog

- [Design Analysis](http://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2014/04/abusing-samba-and-inotify-to-implement.html)
- [Initial Proof of Concept](http://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2014/04/abusing-samba-and-inotify-to-implement.html)